# Android Studio Artic Fox - Java and Kotlin JVM Target - 8 vs 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-arctic-fox

Android Studio built-in JRE is 11 version.
And Artic Fox allows to use Java 11 for compiling projects:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

But we also have Kotlin options

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

What JVM target version should we set now?

`jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` or `jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11`

Kotlin library uses JDK 8:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"`

`kotlin-stdlib-jdk11` doesn't exist yet

All next configurations works with Artic Fox:

#1

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

#2

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

#3

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

But what should we choose?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=nl#java-11

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1, the first choice is the preferred option.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Now coming to the kotlin-stdlib, you can use the jdk8 version.

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

*The kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 library is fully compatible with the JDK 11 SDK.*

Alternatively, for Kotlin only projects you can also ignore the kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 dependency as the Gradle plugin will automatically add the necessary library sources during compilation.

Comment: When you say the preferred option, can you detail why and any sources you have that enforce that opinion please?

Answer (score 3):

According to current documentation use java 8:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

[Android Developer docs (Java8 Support)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#kts) is silent wrt. regarding jvmTarget and Java 11.

[Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew15.html#new-default-jvm-target-1-8) says that 1.8 is the default jvmTarget as of Kotlin 1.5.

Also note that when creating a new Kotlin-based project in the current Android Studio Artic Fox 2021.3.1 Patch 3, it creates a build.gradle with jvmTarget 1.8.